# How to change the background color of default magento generated invoice pdf that's generated to print?

Tags: html, file, pdf, magento, invoice

Can anyone give any idea on where the html files are located that generates the invoice pdf while trying to print it out(in admin).Also I need to modify the background color from the one as in the default one that is generated by magento.
    Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should help get you started: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/how-to/editing_an_invoice_pdf